# How to fire SMS API in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
const String url =
    'http://message.smartwave.co.in/rest/services/sendSMS/sendGroupSms?AUTH_KEY=e&message=&senderId=MyClas&routeId=8&mobileNos=$mobi&smsContentType=';
```

This is giving me error :   **Const variables must be initialized with a constant value. Try changing the initializer to be a constant expression**

Also Please Guide How to fire this POST API in FLUTTER.

Comment: remove const keyword .becuase $mobi is variable at the end of url

Comment: you're trying to use a variable on a constant. Remove the const keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `const` variable is processed at compile time. The `$mobi` in the string is dynamic string interpolation, which can't be combined together with the const keyword. Try removing the const keyword and then, using the `url`.

Reading more about the [const](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const) keyword in Dart should clear this up for you.